# Magento Enterprise - unable to login to admin and products & assets do not appear

Tags: magento-enterprise

Hello I copied a client' magento enterprise installation (ftp) and database to my local server (I’ve done this many times with a community edition but never enterprise).  I changed the “values” web/secure and web/unsecure in core_config_data to reflect localhost.

I can get to home pages and category pages.  However, no products and merchants assets show up on my localhost.

I then tried logging into admin and even though the user/password are correct it just refreshes the admin login page.

Not sure what I’m doing wrong.  Can I copy a enterprise instance to localhost?  Besides changing core_config_data is there anything I need to do?

Thanks

Comment: check if 'var' and 'media' folders exist and if they are writable. Check if you connect to the right database. Check for third party extensions that might be activated on the live domain.

Comment: Did you find an answer here? Please mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1):

The admin login refresh with no error message is due to `web/cookie/cookie_domain`. Search `core_config_data` for this and make sure it is either empty or set to your local domain.

As per the comment, make sure the var and media files are writable. If they are, inspect the urls for the media assets:

- if the urls are still pointing to the server, search core config data for your live site url. Maybe variables like `web/secure/base_media_url` are set explicitly to the server?
- If the urls are pointing locally, is the path correct?
- if the path is correct, does the file really exist? Maybe you did not copy all the media directory.

Comment: I checked all your suggestions and everything seems correct (var/media writable, no other rows in core_config_data pointing to clients urls, etc.).  Though client is doing some funky stuff with their instance; modifying index.php to include another index.php and other rewrites.  So I think its something their doing.  I'm going to ping them and find out. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Migrating an EE store is no different to CE.

1. Dump the DB
2. Transfer files
3. Optional. Replace URLs in DB dump with `sed`
4. Remove downloader config/cache file
5. Import DB

For DB dump and restoration, I recommend using this script, http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/quicker-dumping-of-a-magento-mysql-database-for-branching/

You would use it like this (replace commands as necessary for a remote copy vs local)

```
cd /home/sonassi 
LIVE_DIR="public_html/" 
mkdir subdomains 
rsync -axHPS --delete $LIVE_DIR subdomains/staging --exclude="var/log/*" --exclude="var/cache/*" --exclude="var/session/*" --exclude="var/tmp/*" --exclude="media" --exclude="errors/*" --exclude="*.tgz" --exclude="*.gz" --exclude="app/etc/local.xml" 
ln -s /home/sonassi/public_html/media /home/sonassi/subdomains/staging/media

cd /home/sonassi/public_html 
wget -O mage-dbdump.sh sys.sonassi.com/mage-dbdump.sh 
chmod +x mage-dbdump.sh 
./mage-dbdump.sh 
mv ./var/db.sql ../subdomains/staging/var/db.sql 
mv ./mage-dbdump.sh ../subdomains/staging/
cd ../subdomains/staging/
sed -i 's/www.mydomain.com/staging.mydomain.com/g' ./var/db.sql 
./mage-dbdump.sh --restore
```